# Javascript object constructor - strange behaviour

Tags: javascript, oop, prototype

I've been learning Javascript's prototype inheritance, and I've got the following in a  tag in the body of a html page:

```
function F() {}
//F.prototype = {a:"hello"};
var x = new F();
document.write(x.constructor);
```

This results in the following printout in the browser:

> function F() { }

However , if I uncomment the second line, the following results:

> function Object() { [native code] }

Nevertheless, `x` is still inheriting from the F's prototype, since when I change the last line to the following...

```
document.write(x.a);
```

...I get the following printout:

> hello

I've tried this in Firefox and Safari, and the same thing happens in both.

Does anyone have any idea what on earth is going on here?

Comment: What's so strange about this?  Looks like normal JavaScript to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each object has a `constructor` property in its prototype chain, since each object ultimately inherits from `Object.prototype`.

Since you set a plain object as prototype of `F`, `x.constructor` is now referring to the `constructor` property of that object, which refers to `Object.prototype.constructor`.

The prototype chain looks like this:

```
x -> F.prototype -> Object.prototype
```

and since neither `x` nor `F.prototype` have a `constructor` property, the value of `Object.prototype.constructor` is returned.

The value of `F.prototype` before you override it is something like:

```
F.prototype = {
    constructor: F;
};
```

i.e. it has a `constructor` property. That's why you should always set `constructor` properly if you override the prototype:

```
F.prototype = {a:"hello"};
F.prototype.constructor = F;
```

Comment: So x has inherited the `constructor` property from `{a:"hello"}` in the same way that it inherited the `a` property? So does this mean that `x.constructor.prototype` is of absolutely no use for traversing inheritance trees?

Comment: @user924731: I'm not quite sure what you mean, but maybe my edit clarifies things. If you *override* the prototype, make sure you set the `constructor` function properly.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you've eliminated the default `.constructor` property when you replaced the original `.prototype` object.

So now, when you look for a `.constructor` property it continues down the prototype chain of the given `.prototype` object, until it finds one, which it'll get from the default `Object.prototype`.

When a `.prototype` object has been replaced, some people like to reassign the missing `.constructor`...

```
function F() {}
F.prototype = {a:"hello"};
F.prototype.constructor = F;
```

Comment: Ok. things I had read suggested that you traversed the inheritance tree of an object, `x` by using `x.constructor.prototype`, so I assumed that the `constructor` property would not be overridden.

Comment: @user924731: Yeah, the `.constructor` property is a default property that is provided directly on the default `F.prototype` object for you. If you destroy the default `F.prototype` object, you're also losing any properties it had. That's why it needs to be added in manually.

Comment: @user924731: Not a problem. `:)`